# rust expected named lifetime parameter in solana smart contract with anchor

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

I am working with Solana smart contracts using the anchor library, I am trying to make a struct that will store an array of public keys of other Solana accounts, but it is giving errors around lifetimes and borrowing the array. Can someone explain to me what is wrong and how to fix it? I am still iffy on how stuff like borrowing and ownership works in rust.

```
// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("********************************************");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, entries: u64, keys: [&[u8]]) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.entries = entries;
        ctx.accounts.new_account.keys = keys;
        msg!("Changed entry number to: {}!", entries); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    pub entries: u64,
    pub keys: [&[u8]],
}

#[account]
pub struct NewEntry {
    pubkey: String,
    day: u8,
    month: u8,
    year: u16,
}
```

error log

```
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
 --> /src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | #[program]
  | ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
 
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
  --> /src/lib.rs:34:16
   |
34 |     pub keys: [&[u8]],
   |                ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
 
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> /src/lib.rs:34:16
   |
34 |     pub keys: [&[u8]],
   |                ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
32 ~ pub struct NewAccount<'a> {
33 |     pub entries: u64,
34 ~     pub keys: [&'a [u8]],
   |
 
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> /src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | #[program]
  | ^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
7 ~ #<'a>[program]
8 | mod hello_anchor {
9 |     use super::*;
10~     pub fn initialize<'a>(ctx: Context<Initialize>, entries: u64, keys: [&[u8]]) -> Result<()> {
  |
 
Some errors have detailed explanations: E0106, E0637.
error: could not compile `solpg` due to 4 previous errors
```

Comment: How is the `program` macro defined?

Comment: Not sure, you can check on the anchor documentation but I'll see what I can find

Comment: @Andrew https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/attr.program.html

Comment: I'm not sure about the errors on the `program` macro (maybe it's just referring to the other lifetime issues you have). But for the `NewAccount` issue, you should do what the compiler is recommending: define it with `pub struct NewAccount<'a>` and define the `keys` field as `pub keys: [&'a [u8]]`. This is required because your struct stores references, and Rust needs to know that the references are valid for the entire lifetime of a particular instantiation of the struct.